# Chance Encounter/As Luck Would Have It and reflips/rerolls

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

I'm making an Uncommander deck based around rolling dice and flipping coins, and I'm planning on including [Chance Encounter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=29978) and [As Luck Would Have It](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439491) as alternate win conditions. Both of them place luck counters on themselves when you win a coin flip or roll a dice (respectively), and win you the game if you have enough counters. There are several cards that allow a reflip or a reroll, but I have questions about three.

> #### [Goblin Bookie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9665)
>
> {R}, {T}: Reflip any coin or reroll any die. (Activate this ability only any time it makes sense.)

Goblin Bookie's wording is fairly standard for effects that reroll dice or reflip coins (apart from the timing), but Krark's Thumb - and its Unstable counterpart, Krark's Other Thumb - are worded a bit differently - instead of reflipping, you're ignoring a result.

> #### [Krark's Thumb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=48923)
>
> If you would flip a coin, instead flip two coins and ignore one.

---

> #### [Krark's Other Thumb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439540)
>
> If you would roll a die, instead roll two of those dice and ignore one of those results.

If I reflip/reroll with Goblin Bookie, does the original roll still earn me luck counters? What about with Krark's (Other) Thumb? Does "ignoring" one of the coins means that it doesn't count as a win for me? There might not be a ruling on dice rolls, since only Unsets (as far as I know) have used dice as a mechanic, but coin flips have been used on a number of cards. Chance Encounter is from Odyssey, Krark's Thumb is from Mirrodin; heck, [Mana Crypt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383005) uses coin flips. I would expect there to be an official ruling on flips at least, but neither Krark's Thumb nor Chance Encounter have any Gatherer rulings that clarify things.

Comment: Love un-questions! There are a lot of specific rulings about un-cases that have been made but they're sometimes weird to find. At least we don't have to figure out the precise timing of activating Goblin Bookie!

Comment: Seems like Chance Encounter, Mana Screw, and Krark's Thumb is almost an almost guaranteed win unless your opponent counters.

Comment: The commander for this deck is [Ol' Buzzbark](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439523), so any combination of Chance/As Luck, Mana Screw, and Krark's Thumb basically wins the game (provided X isn't higher than the ceiling of the building we're in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **[As Luck Would Have It](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAs%20Luck%20Would%20Have%20It%5d) works fully with rerolls.**
- **[Chance Encounter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChance%20Encounter%5d) doesn't work with reflips.**
- **The entire game only sees one result from any kind of Krarkish prestidigitation.**

---

Mark Rosewater (the Un-Rules Manager) rules on [Goblin Bookie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Bookie%5d)/ALWHI in [this blog post](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/168138076938/if-i-use-goblin-bookie-to-reroll-a-die-do-both):

> **mikedoesstories asked:** If I use Goblin Bookie to reroll a die, do both die rolls count for As Luck Would Have It or just the rerolled die?
>
> Both rolls count.

MaRo later clarifies that it's based on whether the dice roll would trigger this ability regardless of the outcome ([posted here](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/167897213898/in-your-faq-you-said-that-as-luck-would-have-it)):

> **tarectarec asked:** In your FAQ you said that As Luck Would Have It would get counters from the original dice in case of a reroll. But would Chittering Doom give me a squirrel token if I rolled a 6 but then decided to reroll it (Rolling a 1 this time for example)?
>
> No. Counting die rolls is different than triggering things based upon on a particular outcome.

This wouldn't work with [Krark's Other Thumb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrark%27s%5d%2b%5bOther%5d%2b%5bThumb%5d) since you're specifically instructed to ignore one of the rolls (as far as the rest of the game is concerned, it never happened). For the same reason, [Krark's Thumb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrark%27s%5d%2b%5bThumb%5d) won't work with Chance Encounter.

---

By following this logic in the second case, we can see that a reroll can't trigger Chance Encounter twice because Chance Encounter only triggers on a particular outcome (rather than the flip itself), and there's only one outcome.

Note that we're safe following un-logic in this case, as reflips and rerolls can currently only exist in silver-border.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions in order:

> If I reflip/reroll with Goblin Bookie, does the original roll still earn me luck counters?

Well, the rulings of unsets are kinda messy, especially the older ones. As I see it, **re**flipping a coin or **re**rolling a die would imply that the first result would be ignored in favour of the second. I also wouldn't consider that a replacement or prevention effect, since you're activating the ability *after* the flip/roll has already been made, but *before* whatever effect had you flip the coin or roll the die finishes resolving.

That said, I believe [As Luck Would Have It](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAs%20Luck%20Would%20Have%20It%5d)'s wording is quite clear: **Whenever** you roll a die doesn't check whether an effect tells you to roll a die or not, so it will trigger every time you (legally) roll a die.

> What about with Krark's Thumb? Does "ignoring" one of the coins means that it doesn't count as a win for me?

This one is easier: yes.

If you take a look at the rulings of [Krark's Other Thumb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrark%27s%5d%2b%5bOther%5d%2b%5bThumb%5d), you'll see the following:

> **1/19/2018**: The ignored roll never happened as far as any other cards are concerned.

According to this ruling, when [Krark's Thumb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrark%27s%5d%2b%5bThumb%5d) **ignores** one of the flips, that means that flip never happened as far as any other card is concerned.

Comment: Careful! You've just used an un-card ruling to determine the functionality of a black-bordered card!

Comment: I am well aware of that. The wording on both cards is identical though, and there are no unset-related keywords on the card that would make it ambiguous, so I wouldn't consider that a problem in this specific case.

Comment: Yes, I agree (that's the meaning of the words after all), just thought it was funny that it was used as evidence!

Comment: To be fair, I just couldn't resist. The Thumb/Other Thumb thing just fits perfectly with the question.